# How to get blog archive year selection to update global var in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a drop down selection in a template, I would like the option to update the value of a global var I have set in functions file based on the selection from the list of WP archives by year.

**Drop down**

```
<div>
        <select style="top: -4px;"
                class=" btn-link col-12"
                name="archive-dropdown"
                onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
            <option value=""><?php esc_attr( _e( 'Select From Archive', 'textdomain' ) ); ?></option>
            <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**functions global var**

```
    function test() {
    global $CurrentYear;
    $CurrentYear = '2018';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test' );
```

I am using this var in my query for post to show, the year selected should be set via the drop down and update the global var in turn updating the years to show.

**My goal**
The selected year in the drop down to nothing but update the year value of the global var.

**Note**
no Ajax so ok to reload the page

Comment: Did I completely miss-understand you? hmm.. wondering now. are you talking about how to set a global var or about controlling the data inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard `archive.php` template, you can do the following:

- use [`is_year()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_year/) to check if the query is for the archive for a year
- then use [`get_the_time('Y')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_time/) to get the year from the post date
- The earliest hook you can use for these to work in your `add_action` function is `parse_query`.

Putting this together, you just need to add the following to your `functions.php`:

```
function set_year_from_archive() {
    global $CurrentYear;

    if (is_year())                         // if we're querying for the archive by year
        $CurrentYear = get_the_time('Y');  // get the year and set your variable
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'set_year_from_archive' );
```

**Note:** instead of using a global variable (which is generally discouraged), could you use a function to return the current year (like below) and just call it where you need the year in your query instead? e.g. add this to `functions.php`:

```
function get_year_from_archive() {
    if (is_year())  
        return get_the_time('Y');
}
```

Then you can call this function to add the year to your query.